# Own Camera for each player in multiplayer game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Following unity [official guide for multiplayer game](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/handling-non-player-objects?playlist=29690) and Now I want camera for each player (Just like in counter strike).

I have make A Camera child to the player gameobject but it is not working correctly and showing only one player camera for all player. One Camera is only showing of a specific player.

How do i make separate camera for each player in multiplayer game.? So that a player can view the game from his perspective.

I have also added this to my child camera but nothing worked

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(NetworkView))]
public class PlayerCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        NetworkView objNetworkView = GetComponent<NetworkView>();
        if (objNetworkView.isMine)
        {
            GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
        }
        else {
            GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps do a check on the client, Something like, if(!isLocalPlayer) destroy camera

Comment: @turnipinindia I have update the code i also tried what u said

Comment: you should add the camera to the playercontroller script, then use the isLocalPlayer field to decide on destroying the camera.

Comment: @turnipinindia camera is already child of the player. i have mention it in question